# State of the art hard disk read rate

Tags: hard-drive

What is the maximum read rate of the hard disks used in latest servers. I need this to estimate the running time of my application.

Comment: depends heavily on distribution of reads and size of reads. Also what metric do you want to know? iops, mb/s, latency? Maybe you should just check a couple of benchmarks: http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/enterprise-hard-drive-charts-2010/benchmarks,105.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that determine the speed of hard drive access and each is specific to the server and its configuration.

- Modern SATA hard drives have a transfer limit of 6Gb/s
- Some RAID arrangements can increase throughput, some can reduce throughput.
- Hardware vs Software RAID can have a bearing on the speed, with Software RAID often being slower than Hardware.
- The operating system in use on the server, and how it deals with caching and buffering have a massive influence on the overall speed of the hard disk access.

So we can't say really - you'd have to run some tests to see what kind of throughout you're getting on your specific server.